# Mockito JdbcTemplate with ParameterizedRowMapper returns empty list

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am testing my test class using Mockito (v4.7.0), I have mocked all the layers starting from Service to DAO layer which is where getJdbcTemplate is used to retrieve records from DB and loop through it to apply a business logic. When I run the test,

1> The mocked returned list within the DAO method is 0 for some reason.

2> I also found that the control hasn't traversed the rows to apply the business logic.

Can anyone please guide me how to proceed with this. Below are the sample test class and also the sample rowmapper block.  I have listed what I have already tried that did not work, out in below code. Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AToolControllerMockitoTest  {

    
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule initRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @InjectMocks
    private AToolController aToolController;

    @Mock
    MandatoryAssociationsDTO mandatoryAssociationsDTO;
    
    
    @Before
    public void init() throws NamingException, AppException {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testDoMandatoryAssocaitionsist() throws AppException {

        ExtDTO extDTO;
        
         Mockito.when(mandatoryAssociationsDTO.getPlan_id()).thenReturn(1234);
         Mockito.when(mandatoryAssociationsDTO.getSortOrder()).thenReturn("ASC");
        
         List<MandatoryAssociationsDTO> expectedresultList  = new ArrayList<>();
         expectedresultList.add(new MandatoryAssociationsDTO());
         expectedresultList.add(new MandatoryAssociationsDTO());
         expectedresultList.add(new MandatoryAssociationsDTO());
         expectedresultList.add(new MandatoryAssociationsDTO());
            
         JdbcTemplate mockTemplate = Mockito.mock( JdbcTemplate.class);

        //Example 1 did not work
//       Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(this.getQuery().toString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Object[]>any(), ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<MandatoryAssociationsDTO>>any())).thenReturn(expectedresultList);
        
        //Example 2 did not work
//       Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(this.getQuery().toString(),  ArgumentMatchers.<Object[]>any(),
//               (ResultSetExtractor<T>) ArgumentMatchers.any(MandatoryAssociationsDTO.class)));

        //Example 3 did not work
//       Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(
//                  Mockito.anyString(), 
//                  Mockito.any(Object[].class), 
//                  ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<MandatoryAssociationsDTO>>any())
//              ).thenReturn(expectedresultList);
         
        //Example 4 did not work
//       Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query( Mockito.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Object[]>any(),
//                  ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<MandatoryAssociationsDTO>>any())).thenReturn(expectedresultList);
         
         //Example 5 did not work
         Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Object[]>any(), Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor.class))).thenReturn(expectedresultList);
         

         AToolService ptService = Mockito.spy(new AToolService());
         AToolDAOImpl ptDAO = Mockito.spy(AToolDAOImpl.class);
         ptDAO.setJdbcTemplate(mockTemplate);
         ptService.setPtDAO(ptDAO);
         
         aToolController.setPtService(ptService);
         
         
        
    
        extDTO = aToolController.getMandatoryAssociationsList(mandatoryAssociationsDTO);

        assertEquals(4, ((List<MandatoryAssociationsDTO>) extDTO.getData()).size());

    }   
    
}
```

And the rowmapper block looks as below which is not being traversed or the return list populated with 4 mocked objects.

```
matches = getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlStr, new ParameterizedRowMapper<MandatoryAssociationsDTO>() {
    public MandatoryAssociationsDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        try {
            
            MandatoryAssociationsDTO bean = new MandatoryAssociationsDTO();
            
            
            //Some business logic here for resultset get operations. 
            //I would like to traverse this block via mock if possible.
            
            return bean;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("SQLException: getMandatoryAssociationsList()", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

});

System.out.println("Matches count: "+matches.size()); //is 0
```

Comment: Whitch `query` method of `JdbcTemplate` are you calling? You must mock the exact one. For example this works: `Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Object[].class), Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor.class))).thenReturn(List.of(1, 2, 3)); ResultSetExtractor<Integer> extractor = rs -> rs.findColumn(null);System.out.println(mockTemplate.query("ciao", new Object[10], extractor))`

Comment: @Pp88: Thank you for the response. I tried the above code but still the list named "matches" (in the example above) continue to be empty in the DAO layer even though I pass a pre populated with  "thenReturn(expectedresultList);". Any idea where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Sorry now that I'm reading better you are calling `query` with `ParameterizedRowMapper` and never mocking the correct call try this `Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(ParameterizedRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(expectedresultList);`

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much @Pp88, this worked. Can you please post this as Answer so that I can mark it as resolved. I do not know how to mark a comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moking the wrong `query` method. The one you are moking is:

```
query(String query, Object[] param, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

but in your code you are calling

```
query(String query, ParameterizedRowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

Mocking the correct method will fix the issue:

```
Mockito.when(mockTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(),  Mockito.any(ParameterizedRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(expectedresultList);
```